# Python Popen pty, AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

Tags: python, popen, pty

I have two problems with the below code.
Problem 1 is that `pty` does not work on Windows, works on MAC, but I need this application to run on all platforms.
Problem 2 is when run this I get `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'rstrip'`, not sure how to fix either problem.

```
command1 = transporterLink + " -m verify -f " + indir1 + " -u " + username + " -p " + password + " -o " + logPath + " -s " + provider1 + " -v eXtreme"
master, slave = pty.openpty()
process = Popen(command1, shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=slave, stderr=slave, close_fds=True)
stdout = os.fdopen(master)
import select
q = select.poll()
q.register(stdout,select.POLLIN)
global subject
subject = "Test"
while True:
    wx.Yield()
    line = q.poll()
    if not line:
        continue # no input
    else:
        line = line.rstrip()
        print line
        if "Returning 1" in line:
            result1 = "Verify FAILED!"
            subject = "FAILED! - "
            self.sendEmail(self)
            break
        if "Returning 0" in line:
            result1 = "Verify PASSED!"
            subject = "PASSED! - "
            self.sendEmail(self)
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

[`q.poll`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.poll.poll) returns a list. Lists don't have the `rstrip` method.

Comment: Thanks Nigel, any suggestions please?